# Symfony2 - insert data with DateType

Tags: php, symfony, date

I would like the user to be able to manually enter the date that will be saved to the database. My MonthType looks like:

```
class MonthType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
    $builder->add(
        'name',
        TextType::class,
        [
            'label' => 'label.name',
            'required' => true,
            'attr' => [
                'max_length' => 128,
            ],
        ]
    );
    $builder->add(
        'dateStart',
        DateType::class,
        [
            'label' => 'label.dateStart',
            'format' => 'yyyy-MM-dd',
        ]
    );
    $builder->add(
        'dateEnd',
        DateType::class,
        [
            'label' => 'label.dateEnd',
            'format' => 'yyyy-MM-dd',

        ]
    );
    $builder->add(
        'upper_limit',
        MoneyType::class,
        [
            'label' => 'label.upper_limit',
            'currency' => false,
            'required' => true,
        ]
    );
    }
}
```

My controller looks like:

```
class MonthController implements ControllerProviderInterface
{

    public function connect(Application $app)
    {
        $controller->match('/add', [$this, 'addAction'])
            ->method('POST|GET')
            ->bind('month_add');

        return $controller;
    }
    /**
    * Add action.
    */
    public function addAction(Application $app, Request $request)                               
    {
        $month = [];
        $userRepository = new UserRepository($app['db']);

        $token = $app['security.token_storage']->getToken();
        if (null !== $token) {
            $user = $token->getUser();
            $userLogin = $user->getUsername();
        }

        $form = $app['form.factory']->createBuilder(MonthType::class, $month)->getForm();
        $form->handleRequest($request);

        if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
            $monthRepository = new MonthRepository($app['db']);
            $monthRepository->save($form->getData(), $userLogin);

            $app['session']->getFlashBag()->add(
                'messages',
                [
                    'type' => 'success',
                    'message' => 'message.element_successfully_added',
                ]
            );

            return $app->redirect($app['url_generator']->generate('month_index'), 301);
        }

        return $app['twig']->render(
            'history/add.html.twig',
            [
                'month' => $month,
                'form' => $form->createView(),
                'user_id' => $userRepository->findUserId($userLogin),
            ]
        );
    }
}
```

And in repository I have:

```
/**
 * Save record.
 */
public function save($month, $userLogin)
{
    $user_id = $this -> findUserIdByLogin($userLogin);
    $month['user_id'] = $user_id;
    $month['remained'] = $month['upper_limit'];

    if (isset($month['id']) && ctype_digit((string) $month['id']) && isset($user_id)) {
        // update record
        $id = $month['id'];
        unset($month['id']);

        return $this->db->update('month', $month, ['id' => $id]);
    } else {
        // add new record
        return $this->db->insert('month', $month);
    }
}
```

When I try to save record I get an error: 
An exception occurred while executing 'INSERT INTO month (name, dateStart, dateEnd, upper_limit, user_id, remained) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)' with params ["june 2012", {"date":"2012-06-01 00:00:00.000000","timezone_type":3,"timezone":"Europe/Berlin"}, {"date":"2012-06-30 00:00:00.000000","timezone_type":3,"timezone":"Europe/Berlin"}, 7600, "1", 7600]:

Catchable Fatal Error: Object of class DateTime could not be converted to string

So I tried to make something like that:

```
    public function save($month, $userLogin)
    {
        $user_id = $this -> findUserIdByLogin($userLogin);
        $month['user_id'] = $user_id;
        $month['remained'] = $month['upper_limit'];

        $dateStart = new \DateTime($month['dateStart']);
        $month['dateStart'] = $dateStart->format('Y-m-d');
        $dateEnd = new \DateTime($month['dateEnd']);
        $month['dateEnd'] = $dateEnd->format('Y-m-d');
        ...//
    }
```

but I received:
DateTime::__construct() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given

Comment: whqt is your `$month['dateStart']` ? have you dumped it ? isn't it a datetime object yet ?

Comment: dump($month['dateStart']) gives this
 DateTime {#678 ▼
  +"date": "2012-01-01 00:00:00.000000"
  +"timezone_type": 3
  +"timezone": "Europe/Berlin"
}

Answer (score 1):

Seems that you have both `$month['dateStart']` and `$month['dateEnd']` as DateTime (look at database exception `{"date":"2012-06-01 00:00:00.000000","timezone_type":3,"timezone":"Europe/Berlin"}`).

So you can use directly as `$dateStart` or `$dateEnd` as it:

`$month['dateStart']->format('Y-m-d')`

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried this one, but it gives the same error as without my modification.

Comment: have you tried by `new DateTime($month['dateStart']->format('Y-m-d')`?

Comment: Yes. No change.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem. I used this: http://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-3-1-datetime-normalizer
and wrote

```
$serializer = new Serializer(array(new DateTimeNormalizer('Y-m-d')));
$month['dateStart'] = $serializer->normalize($month['dateStart']);
$serializer = new Serializer(array(new DateTimeNormalizer('Y-m-d')));
$month['dateEnd'] = $serializer->normalize($month['dateEnd']);
```